# Opensuse 13.1 wifi doesn't work (intel k53E laptop)

Tags: networking, opensuse

I downloaded opensuse to dual boot from a CD and got everything installed.

At first, my wifi was working. Then I went to school and it stopped working and wouldn't connect to anything even when I went home.

I re-downloaded Linux and it was fine until I went back to school and it stopped working again. Someone told me it didn't like the way I authenticate things. I use kde wallet and I tried stuff without it and it still didn't work. I also tried rfkill but my wifi wasn't hard blocked. Any ideas?

My friend thinks I'm being hardblocked

I can only connect to unsecured networks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "hard blocked", could you please explain that?

Comment: I mean hard fail

Comment: Did you reboot into Windows somewhere?

Comment: It's a dual boot system, I guess I can reboot to windows if I want

Comment: But did you?  If you reboot from Windows into Linux and WiFi works, but booting from cold into Linux doesn't then I'd consider whether the WiFi adapter has firmware that needs loading for it to work and that Linux isn't doing this.

Comment: When I start up my system i boot into Linux or windows, I don't boot into windows then go into linux

Comment: garethTheRed is asking you to boot into Windows and see if WiFi works. If that does then check if you reboot (not shutting down) from Windows to Linux causes WiFi to work.

Comment: It works with windows but I'm not sure how to boot into Linux FROM windows

Comment: add more info about you card. If you use cable instead of wifi does it work?

Comment: I got a USB wifi adapter. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

This LT uses a cheap wifi cbipset that uses firmware & software drivers for some of its base functions. It's a pain with Win 7 too. You did the best thing by buying a Linux compatible USB wifi device. I think it will work off a better quality USB hub also.